# Do I have to parametrize ellipse to find integral in closed curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the contour integral $\large\int_\gamma  (e^{-z^2})/(z^2)$ where $\gamma$ is the ellipse $a cos t +ibsint$ where $a,b>0$, and $t$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the fact that z=0 (singularity) lies inside this ellipse and so its winding number is 1. Then I'm using the residue theorem:

$\large\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 2\pi i * Res(f,0)*I(\gamma,z) = 0$ where $I(\gamma,z)$ is the winding number.

Am I taking the write aproach?

Comment: Yup, that's right. +1